# AppEngine Bulk Upload List Property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulk-load

I have a model with a list property.

I have a csv that has each list data that looks like this.

[u'1234567']

The list has only one item each.

My bulkloader.yaml has configured import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(list). It uploads the above list property as [u'[', u'u', u"'", u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u"'", u']']

How should I configure the import_transform in order to upload it properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import_transform: lambda x: [x] if x else None
```

Comment: Didn't work for me yet. It says...

Error parsing yaml file:
Unable to asssign value 'lambda x' to attribute 'import_transform':
Invalid code for import_transform. Code: "lambda x". Details: unexpected EOF while parsing <<string>, line 1>

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm. You may have to put the transform in a Python module, then import it and use it in the same way the bulkloader imports other modules in the yaml config.

Comment: You can quote the lambda expression and make it into a string, `import_transform: "lambda x: [x] if x else None"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use json, it work for me.
Like this:

```
import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(json.loads)
export_transform: transform.none_if_empty(json.dumps)
```

Remember to import json in python_preamble block.